# How to return a column in Select Distinct - but exclude it in the Distinct statement

Tags: sql, distinct, ssms-2016

I have a table with a data that looksl ike this:

```
 Num      Name      City       State
 12       Bob       NYC        NY
 13       Bob       NYC        NY
 17       John      Miami      FL
 18       John      Miami      FL
```

I'm trying to do a DISTINCT on this table with 2 caveats:

-- don't include Num in Distinct

-- have the Num in end result

Goal (Irrelevant which Num is return, as long as it is returned)

```
 Num      Name      City       State
 13       Bob       NYC        NY
 17       John      Miami      FL
```

I know I can do a Distinct without excluding Num in it to get the result like so:

```
 Select Distinct * from Tbl1
```

But what if I want to include Num in the end result?

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result. It's not clear what you want to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `group by` with `max` or `min` since which num is not important :

```
select max(num) as num, Name, City, State
from Tbl1
group by Name, City, State
```